# How can you iterate between a letter string on the text field of a button in ASP.NET/C# enviroment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, browser

I have 9 buttons set up as a tic tac toe game. It is web browser based so for the two players to play, they must connect to the browser URL, and enter a que for a game. When they're in the game, the first player is decided by who joined the session first. When he presses a button on his browser, it sends a Request/response to the other player's browser to have that button filled in as the 'X' he has played. The the second player will press one of the nine buttons and have his text field filled in as 'O'. Again, this will send request/response to the host which sends to the first player's browser to show up that player two has played. What I mean by response/request is the validity checking of one game played on two browsers.

My question is, how can iterate between X's and O's between the two players playing?

Comment: What do you mean "it sends a Request to the other player's browser"? A browser cannot accept incoming requests.

Comment: It "talks" to the other browser, the second player is playing in to make sure that what player one sees on the screen is the same as player two. Could a button not send validity tests? Request is probably not the proper way to say so.

Comment: You don't need to "iterate" between the letters. You seem to already know which player is player one and which is player two so just assign them they correct character string to use

Comment: Oh, I guess I was overthinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to provide real time interaction between multiple users in a web scenario, you need to use either long polling / web sockets. If you are working with ASP.Net, you can use libraries like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) or [XSockets.Net](http://xsockets.net/) which abstracts out the long polling / web sockets functionality depending on the browser capabilities. You can look at examples in these sites to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: There must be a way to do it in the visual basic '08 environment right?

Comment: Not sure if SignalR works with ASP.Net versions less than 4.0. I know that it works in Visual Studio 2010, maybe you can download the express edition and try creating a asp.net 4.0 / asp.net mvc 3 application. [Here](http://zooplet.com/tictactoe/) is a tic tac toe done using SignalR, which you can see by opening the link in 2 browsers. I don't know where the source code for this is though.